# Feed powershell console that is running .exe from multiple different php script one after another

Tags: php, powershell

Here is what I have and what I would like to do :
I'm running a php script from an AJAX request, this php script is running a .exe with different args on Powershell.

```
shell_exec("(echo input1_on_exe&& echo input2_on_exe) | program.exe");
```

I'am using the Powershell return to do some stuff on client side. Everything is running smoothly.

Now is what I'm trying to achieve:

Each time I do this AJAX request it open a new powershell, and I would like to use the same powershell as before and not opening a new one to feed it with some new inputs.

Edit:

The reason is that the .exe is opening a big file at the beginning (20GB) and need some inputs to treat this file. The problem is that each requests come after another, so I have to reload this big file each time to feed the news inputs.

Edit2:

AJAX REQUEST 1

```
shell_exec("(echo load_file&& echo input1_on_exe&& echo input2_on_exe) | program.exe");
```

AJAX REQUEST 2

```
shell_exec("(echo load_file&& echo input3_on_exe&& echo input4_on_exe) | program.exe");
```

I want to keep the same console to escape loading the file a second time

Edit3 :

The file is an encrypted file created from .exe so it need the .exe to be treated.

Edit4:

Each new inputs need previous outputs to be found

Any ideas? I hope I clearly explained my problem.

Comment: `Each time I do this AJAX request it open a new powershell, and I would like to use the same powershell as before and not opening a new one to feed it with some new inputs`...why? What difference would it make? Fundamentally though it's not really possible because each request to the server kicks off a new PHP script in a different context, which will in turn kick off a new powershell script in a different context. If you explain what problem you're actually trying to solve with your question, we might be able to suggest how you could approach it better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to do it because the .exe I'm running need to load a big file at the beginning. Basically the .exe is treating this big file using some input. The fact is it's making each request really long because of the loading time. Is it clear ?

Comment: No problem. Happy to assist if you want to explain...

Comment: up message edited ;)

Comment: Well, it's a _bit_ clearer. What is the big file, and what does the powershell script do with it? And how big is "big" exactly? A few MB? GB? Or what? Do you need all of it each time you run the script - could it be split up? Could the contents go into a database instead? Why do you need powershell specifically - could you not do this task direct with PHP? We need a little more detail, still.

Comment: It's a file (20-30GB) created from the same .exe, the file is encrypted so I can't access to the data without using the .exe. Yes it needs to load the entire file to get a return from the inputs. If I make 1 script with 10 inputs there is no problem, it goes fast because I only load once the file. But as I explained the inputs come one after another and I have to reload the file each time. Thanks to you I'v edited my main post.

Comment: Can you not ask the user to provide a whole set of inputs at once, and then just execute all of them in one session?

Comment: No, each new inputs need previous outputs to be found

Comment: But previously you said `If I make 1 script with 10 inputs there is no problem, it goes fast because I only load once the file.`...are you saying that's not actually a valid use case - i.e. that situation cannot occur in reality?

Comment: As long as you spin up new PS process, it will have to reload the 20GB file into Memory to perform operations on it. To allow the possibility of what you want, the process should exist independently and persistently. You can achieve this if you can convert the exe to run as a "server" service that accepts external requests. This can be done using a Windows Service or a hosting ur own Custom API. This would mean, having a process that has 20GB worth of file in memory. A lot of that is possibly going to go into virtual memory but it will leave its impact on RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is exactly what I want to do, but have no clue on how to proceed, do you have any sharing that can help ?

Comment: @ADyson Yes it is a use case and it's working perfectly but as I tried to explain you, there is the others possibilities of new inputs coming. And it has to load the file again making the application too slow.

Comment: If you don't have the ability to read the file without the .exe, and you don't have the ability to change the .exe, then there is nothing you can do - it seems that dealing with the file happens within the .exe, therefore unless you can modify the .exe there's no way you can make it process the data differently.

Comment: @ADyson I dont need to process the data differently, I just don't want to reload the file each time I run a php script. I know that the exe need to load the file but it has already be done previously, that's the reason on why I'm trying to keep the same console used previously.

Comment: "processing the data" includes opening the file and reading from it, and holding the data in memory. That's what I meant. But the bottom line is, if the .exe is doing the opening, then you have to modify the .exe.

Comment: @ADyson message edited up

Comment: You cannot make PHP "share" an already-running instance of the .exe, nor can multiple instances of the .exe share the data a previous instance has loaded into the computer's RAM - for one thing it will violate all sorts of O/S memory-security rules, and for another (in the first scenario) the .exe would have no idea how to deal with this second process trying to somehow muscle in on it.

Comment: I heard about powershell session, I can't do something with that ?

Comment: I don't think so. It might be useful if you wanted to share powershell variables, but you don't - you want to share something which is controlled by a compiled executable, and (as far as I know from what you've said) it has no capability to share it. Also a PS session has to be created from another PS script, and then that calling script can cause the data to be shared between the sessions it creates. AFAIK the data cannot be shared _outside_ that, so you'd be back to square 1 because each AJAX script would initialise a new PS script which creates a new PS Session...

Comment: The fundamental issue here seems to be that you've got large amounts of data stored in an inefficient storage format, with (what I assume is) a non-modifiable proprietary program being the only way to access and decrypt the data. Your bottleneck is, unfortunately in this case, pretty much the only bit of the application which you don't seem to be in control of. Ideally, you'd decrypt this data and store it somewhere else - and probably employ liberal use of in-memory caching to serve it more efficiently to web clients, but it sounds like you don't have the option to pre-decrypt it?

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot for your time, what do you think about Sid proposal above ?

Comment: https://piofiles.com/docs/upi_documentation/  This is the way to communicate with the .exe and I'm using PS from a php script to feed inputs.

Comment: Well putting it into a service is a reasonable idea, but there would still have to be a way for other processes to interact with it. Again, if you can't change the .exe (and you seem to be implying that you can't although you've never actually confirmed or denied that) then you still won't be able to achieve that goal. Having said that, the assumption of the service idea is that the PC can have 20GB of RAM being consumed, it's not typical and unlikely to work well. This is why people employ dedicated caching solutions.

Comment: Maybe I'm making it impossible by using powershell. From the documentation I sent you do you think of another way to feed inputs to the UPI coming from client side ?

Comment: Hm, judging by that website it's _possible_ you might be able to communicate with it in-memory, as it does sound like it has a server-like component to it, if you could keep that part running in a separate process in the background without restarting it every time. You need to start the solver program on its own, and then have your PHP call the UPI. I agree I'm not sure Powershell is really necessary, you could probably just call the command direct from PHP, but neither is powershell particularly hindering you I don't think.

Comment: It's not really clear though from the UPI documentation how you're supposed to communicate with an already-running instance. It seems to imply you'd start a new instance of solver from the client program and then continue to communicate with it via STDIO. It doesn't say anything about communicating with an already-running instance. You might need to get support from the vendor of PioSolver to clarify that. It does say it's a "standalone console application" rather than a server appliance so it may not have any open sockets or anything where it listens for external connections.

Comment: Seems a very good idea, but have no clue on how to proceed. How is it possible for me to feed inputs into a running .exe. I feel so newbie, so sorry. If you want to speak audio let me know and aswell can agree on some bucks for your time. thanks

Comment: `How is it possible for me to feed inputs into a running .exe`...I think probably you can't, judging by the docs. It seems to be designed for one client program to access it at once. Communication seems to be via the (emulated) command-line once you have started the program...but obviously for that you need to be in the same session which started the program. Normally the architecture of a multi-user program would be that it opens a socket and clients can all connect to it on that socket (like a webserver). But again you need to clarify with the vendor because the docs are vague.

Comment: Ok, I'm contacting the support now, again thanks a lot for all your informations.

Comment: Ok, I contacted them and they said : 
''I don't think you can
I have never heard of something similar
If we wanted to allow this users we'd use sockets or something similar
But the owner process owns the input and output of subproccess
And I'm not aware of a mechanism to hijack it
You could write a separate app that only starts pio
And this one would allow other processes to call in''

Now I'll explore this way, what do you think about it ?

Comment: Yeah I guess effectively you'd have your own service running which accepts socket connections - and your PHP would connect to that, and the service would then be connected to a single instance of pio via command-line. It would probably work, just a more complex architecture to create.